# Перемешать значения в двумерном массиве Python

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, list

Есть массив

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[11,22,33,44,55],[111,222,333,444,555]]
```

Нужно чтобы генерировалась строка с разными значениями из каждого листа, например:

```
str = 3 11 444
```

или

```
str = 4 22 111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

mylist = [[1,2,3,4,5],[11,22,33,44,55],[111,222,333,444,555]]
str = [random.choice(x) for x in mylist]
print(str)
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/921440)

Comment: скорее: `' '.join([str(random.choice(x)) for x in mylist])`?

Comment: @MaxU Это оставим для домашнего задания :)

Comment: @MaxU `' '.join(map(str, map(random.choice, arr)))`

Comment: @Alban, тоже вариант, но я стараюсь [не злоупотреблять `map` без необходимости](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)